# Install Tomcat on remote server and deploy web-service on it

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, remote-server

I have a Java web-service which currently runs on a local tomcat server. I use Eclipse as IDE.
Now I need to migrate my service on remote server, so I need:

1) install Apache Tomcat on remote server (now I have only address of server and nothing installed on it)

2) install Cassandra database on server (it's used in my web service) // I generally know how to do it, so this part can be skipped

3) deploy web service on remote server via Eclipse

I'm a complete noob in this sphere, so would appretiate any help - ideally, I need step-by-step manual.

Comment: You will need remote access to the server to install Tomcat. Look for Eclipse + export WAR, and Tomcat + Deploy WAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestions in the comment made by Sérgio should help you finding the right answers.

Basically you need to start with the installation of tomcat on that remote server. For that the best way to begin is to check the tomcat documentation on http://tomcat.apache.org/ . How to install is very specific to the OS running on that server and the way you can access this system.

Next step is to export your application from eclipse towards an archive tomcat accepts. I expect it to be a WAR file (rather than EAR). From eclipse menu choose "File" > "Export" then select "Web" > "WAR file" and follow the wizard.

Now you can either install this war to the server using a web app (available via tomcat website) for deployment or by putting it in the right folder on the server installation. Again visit tomcat website for documentation.